# How to remove chars in a string, and use that for another string

Tags: java

I am rather new at java, and I know this cant be too difficult, but I cant quite figure it out.

```
String xxChange = request.getParameter("XXChange");     
String yyChange = request.getParameter("YYChange");    
String zzChange = request.getParameter("ZZChange");  
String aaaChange = request.getParameter("AAChange");
```

So basically I am getting these parameters and just setting them to strings.  Each one of these strings has multiple numbers then two letters after it, and my question is how do I remove the letters and set it to a new string.  Fyi....the number in front of the letters is on a sequence, and could grow from being 1 digit to multiple, so i dont think i can do string.Substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove the last two characters, so use substring like this:

```
String s = "123AB";
String numbers = s.substring(0, s.length() - 2);
```

Comment: Sounds like the OP wants to remove the prefixed numbers, and keep the characters after.

Comment: This works great, exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for the quick response/help.

Answer (score 1):

You could test something like

```
String value = "123ABC";
System.out.println(value.replaceAll("\\d+(.*)", "$1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the last two letters:

```
String input = "321Ab";
String lastTwo = input.substring(input.length() - 2);
```

---

If you need both the digits and the letters use a regular expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(\\w{2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher("321Ab");
if (m.matches()) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)); // 321
    String letters = m.group(2);               // Ab
    ...
}
```